# неподписанный слитно

Tags: слитно-раздельно

О том, как теоретически будет реализовано подтверждение неподписанных в срок счетов, рассказал преподаватель нашего курса.

Comment: Максим, вы задаёте уже 3-й однообразный вопрос. Скажите, пожалуйста, вам было непонятно мое объяснение?

Answer (score 1):

Думаю, что здесь НЕ с причастием ПОДПИСАННЫХ пишется раздельно, так как имеется зависимое слово "в срок" : "О том, как теоретически будет реализовано подтверждение не подписанных в срок счетов, рассказал  преподаватель нашего курса".

Answer (score -1):

Думаю что раздельно. *Не* в причастных оборотах пишется раздельно.

Comment: Иваныч, то есть "подтверждение без подписи счетов в срок"? Так по-вашему? Замена разве возможна?

Comment: Да, ошибся. Спасибо.

Comment: Игорь, Насколько я помню со школьных времен, причастный оборот - это причастие с зависимыми словами. Отсюда,  “не” всегда пишется раздельно (в причастном обороте). Теперь о предложении “Книга лежала на столе, совершенно непрочитанная.” Мое чувство языка подсказывает что это выражение неприемлемо. Как может книга быть совершенно непрочитанной?  Или есть совершенно прочитанные книги? Иначе говоря, это искусственная конструкция и слово совершенно там не к месту.

Comment: Похоже что я ответил на удаленный комментарий. Словом, разногласий нет. Спасибо. А если он "в доработке," то оставлю пока свой.